# BlazorプロジェクトでのEPSON製のePOSでのWebアプリ開発

Tags: javascript, razor

Blazorのフレームワークを使用して、ePOS制御でプリンターから印刷するWebアプリを開発しています。
サンプルソースとして、とりあえず印刷できるアプリを作成しようとしているのですが、良いサンプルが
のっているサイトなどがあれば教えていただきたいです。